# How do I delete a shared parameter in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

We are using Microsoft Test Manager 2015 Update 1. I created a couple of shared parameters to see how they work.

How do you delete them? I can make them inactive, but they still display in the list of available shared parameters. I don't see a delete button and when I searched online I found nothing about it.

Comment: There is a delete button in VSTS, but it errors saying Shared Parameters cannot be deleted. Guess you use the answer below, or get onto MS about it :)

Comment: If they are still in use, I can see why you could not delete them. But the ones I'm talking about have never been used.

Comment: Which version of TFS do you have that you see the delete button?

Comment: I think it will be in Update 2... Delete buttons have only just appeared in the last few sprints on VSTS. The one I tried to delete was unused. I think this is just a feature that isn't finished yet, sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared Parameters are stored in TFS as Work Items so you *could* destroy it (there may be a better way but I don't know of one)

[Remove or delete work items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items)

On-premise you'll have to use the **witadmin.exe** command line tool (*%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE*) with the **destroywi** option.  You'll need to know the ID of the Shared Parameter Work Item you want to get rid of.

```
witadmin destroywi /collection:http://TFSServerName:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /id:123
```